# Facebook Requests Dialog request links to "The page you requested was not found"

Tags: ios, facebook

I have an app on iOS which uses Facebook SDK v3.23.2, and uses `[FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession]` to implement an "Invite your friends" mechanic.

Invitations sent using this method appear as requests in the recipient's Facebook app, however activating the request redirects to a page in the FB app with the text: "The page you requested was not found".

This used to redirect the user to the app store.

I am aware that v4 of the FB SDK provides a bunch of new App Invite options.

Are these requests on v3 no longer supported?

Comment: It's still supported. Can you provide some code snippet where you implement the invite dialog?

Comment: Hi, I don't implement the dialog; the snippet I provided on iOS is what shows it.

Comment: I mean, how do you call the `FBWebDialogs`? What are your parameters? If it used to work before and it doesn't now, it might be a bug.